# In a table with multiple rows, multiply every value in a row by the same defined value

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a tab delimited table (Table1)

```
 a b c
A 0.5 0.2 0
B 0 0.5 0.4
C 1 0.3 0.4
D 0.2 0 0.2
```

And a tab delimited file (File1)

```
A 0.3
B 1
C 0.5
D 0.5
```

I want to multiple every number in each row in Table1 (for example, Row A (0.5 0.2 and 0)),by the number in the row with the same name in File1 (Row A (0.3)). So for Row A it would be 0.5 * 0.3, 0.2 * 0.3 and 0 * 0.3.

Desired output:

```
 a b c
A 0.15 0.06 0
B 0 0.5 0.4
C 0.5 0.15 0.2
D 0.1 0 0.1
```

To clarify, this is an example table. The letters are variables representing the column/row names - there may be hundreds of columns and rows.
Note that the real column/row names may contain numbers, which should not be altered by the script. For Example, Row "A" might be named "ABC123"

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add your attempts to the question? Users are encouraged to show their efforts before posting. You may still get an answer, but learn by doing is often the best method.

Comment: is line order important or only first word (search kriteria) used for pairing? how should duplicates in Table1 or File1 handled?

Comment: Are the row names always in the same order between the 2 files or could file 1 row names be `A B C` while file2 is `B C A` for example? Are all row names from file1 always present in file2 and vice-versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$ awk -F"\t" '
    { 
        if(NR==FNR){
            a[$1]=$2;
        }
        else{
            if(FNR==1){print; next} 
            printf "%s",$1; 
            for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
                printf "\t%0.2f",$i*a[$1]
            }
            printf "\n"
        }
    }' table2 table1 
    a    b    c
A    0.15    0.06    0.00
B    0.00    0.50    0.40
C    0.50    0.15    0.20
D    0.10    0.00    0.10
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: `print ""` would be better than `printf "\n"` since it's briefer and, more importantly, uses whatever value `ORS` has instead of hardcoding the value that you hope/assume `ORS` has.

Comment: @EdMorton seeing as I know what the ORS is, I don't see much benefit in that, and chose `printf` to make it explicit and easier for the OP to understand.